# Does Java Iterator do a second traversal to remove?

Tags: java, iterator, traversal, singly-linked-list

If I use a linked list Iterator to find an element, does calling remove() cause the Iterator to traverse the list again? The code is below

```
//The list is LinkedList<String> list; and has already been populated

Iterator itar = list.iterator();

 while(itar.hasNext())
{
           if(itar.next().equalsIgnoreCase("Foo")) 
               itar.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `LinkedList` in Java is a *doubly* linked list, meaning each node has a reference to the next and previous in the list.

When the iterator does a remove, it has a reference to the current node and simply reassigns the references in the next and previous (updating the head and tail references for the list itself if needed).

So, no; there is no additional iteration performed.

Also worth noting is that Java is open source these days. You can view the source for `LinkedList` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java) with the code the iterator's `remove()` calls [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.remove%28java.util.LinkedList.Entry%29)

**Edit to Add:** As noted in the comments, an iterator for a singly-linked list implementation could easily keep track of the previous node it iterated over and perform the same operation.

Comment: Oh downvoter, please do tell. Inquiring minds would like to know.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but .. even in a SLL, the iterator could trivially store the previous node iterated.

Comment: @user2864740 Agreed, but the question was specifically about Java's `LinkedList` which is why I mentioned the ease of which it's done without needing anything else.

Comment: Edited to read a bit better and note that this wasn't unique to a DLL implementation.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but looking at Sun/Java's (not OpenJDK) `LinkedList`'s source code, it does indeed traverse the list. `LinkedList.iterator()` returns a `ListItr` which extends `Itr`. `Itr.remove` calls `AbstractList.this.remove(lastRet)`. `LinkedList.remove(int)` calls `entry(int)` which does indeed iterate (see one of two for loops around line 370). It loops from the beginning or end, setting `e = e.next` or `e = e.previous`, thus on average it's reassigning half the nodes' next/prev pointers.

Comment: @SteveKuo Those methods are overriden in `LinkedList`. The openjdk code I linked shows that `iterator()` calls `listIterator()` which calls `listIterator(0)` which returns an instance of the private class `ListItr` defined in `LinkedList.java` (implements `ListIterator`)  which then calls `LinkedList.remove(node)` which is also linked above.

Comment: You are indeed correct. `LinkedList` has its own `ListItr` which has `remove()` with the reference fixup logic as you described.

Answer (score 0):

No, iterators always only iterate once even if you call remove().

Removing an item from a linked list updates the relevant pointers without requiring any further iterations.

Comment: Depends on the implementation. Look at `AbstractList`'s source code, `Itr.remove()` calls remove(int) which does iterate.

Comment: Where does Itr iterate on remove()? It removes the item using remove(int) and adjusts its cursor. No iteration that I can see?

Comment: Certainly the Iterator itself does not reiterate. Internally, there *may* be an iteration over the data structure, but that's never revealed publicly.

Comment: `ArrayList.remove(int)` does iterate, see my detailed comment under the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, it will do an array copy which is an internal implementation detail. The iterator object that the user has a reference to does not iterate again.

Comment: It's all internal implementation, that's what this question is asking.

Comment: That wasn't my reading of the question, but re-reading it I think it's ambiguous. So what you say is definitely worth pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

**No** Iterator does not start from beginning but it will point to the next element if exist.I want to make you aware about one important thing of Iterator that they are **"Fail Fast"** means if a collection is modified by one of its methods after an iterator is created for that collection, the iterator immediately becomes invalid and operations performed with the iterator after this point throw **ConcurrentModificationExceptions**.